# vb.net datagrid view multiple Datasources

Tags: vb.net, data-binding

i have 4 data sources that i Want to bind to a datagridview, so it will be like

```
 datasource Me.DataGridView1.DataSource = Me.bindingSource1 'rows 0 to 500
 datasource Me.DataGridView1.DataSource = Me.bindingSource2 'rows 501 to 1000 
 datasource Me.DataGridView1.DataSource = Me.bindingSource3 'rows 1001 to 1500
 datasource Me.DataGridView1.DataSource = Me.bindingSource4 'rows 1501 to 2000
```

how can it be done?

Comment: What type are the bindingSources?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you must combine these, then you should use the [Merge](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.merge.aspx) function of a datatable.

```
Dim aggregateTable as New DataTable("AggTbl")
aggregateTable.Merge(Me.bindingSource1)
aggregateTable.Merge(Me.bindingSource2)
aggregateTable.Merge(Me.bindingSource3)
aggregateTable.Merge(Me.bindingSource4)

Me.DataGridView1.DataSource = aggregateTable
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't.  A DataGridView can only have one DataSource at a time.

I know this is related to your previous question trying to use multiple threads to update the grid, but if you are dead set on using multiple threads to write to the grid, you are going to have to lock the data source to do the update.

Comment: but how come each column can have a datasource?

Comment: but there is no point of using threads if i am going to lock it!

Comment: @user1570048 ComboBoxes can have their own datasource for their own dropdown list, but the selected value of the combobox comes from the grid's datasource.

Comment: Multiple threads interacting with any control is a recipe for disaster. You can spawn the threads to get the data, and then when they are all done use the main thread to update the grid.

Comment: @user1570048 `but there is no point of using threads if i am going to lock it!`  That's what we've been trying to tell you.

Comment: @StingyJack this is what i am trying to do but i started programming about 2 weeks ago so i would appreciate a sample code

Comment: @LarsTech but there must be a solution other than locking!

Comment: If you just started two weeks ago, you are a few months away from worrying about threads. "Premature optimization is the root of all evil" Just make the code work, worry about performance later.

Comment: use paging instead Or handle any event to re-bind the control to the new datasource depending on what data you want to show.